# Only return one row in foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm starting with Laravel and I'm having trouble getting the results of a query on the laravel blade.

From a list obtained through a query to MySQL 'mysql', I want to check the name it has in another table of another 'tienda' database.

Everything is fine, but it only returns the last value of the second query, it does not return all the values ​​of the $ products query with its corresponding name obtained in $ products_name.

Controller

```
    $productos = [
        'id' => $id
    ];

    $products = DB::connection('mysql')
                ->SELECT("SELECT * FROM promociones_product WHERE id_promo = $id", $productos);

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        $products_name = collect(DB::connection('tienda')
                ->table('ps_product_lang')
                ->where('id_product', $product->id_product)
                ->get(['name', 'id_product']));
    }

    return view('promociones-products')->with('promo', $products_name);
```

Blade

```
        @foreach($promo as $product)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $product->id_product }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
                </tr>
        @endforeach
```

I need to make a query against the 'mysql' database and, with those results, consult its name in another database, and all the values ​​are printed on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried checking your code? Obviously, `$products_name` does only contain the last product's name, as you override that variable in each iteration

Comment: You are overriding the same object while looping. Try $products_name[] instead of $products_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues with the code you provided.

To start with, in your loop you are creating a new collection called 'products_name' on each loop which keeps overwriting itself.

There are lots of ways of approaching this however how I would do it is below:

```
$promo = []; // Initialise a new array called promo

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    // Append the collection to the new array
    $promo[] = collect(DB::connection('tienda')
            ->table('ps_product_lang')
            ->where('id_product', $product->id_product)
            ->get(['name', 'id_product']));
}
```

Now you have an array with all of the products in collections.
Now the loop to get that data should work.

You can then return the data to the view using a couple of methods, my preferred method is indeed `compact()` seen below:

```
return view('promociones-products', compact('promo'));
```

What `compact()` will do is grab any variable names mentioned in the view and pass it through to the view. This compact will pass the `$promo` variable to the view.

Comment: The dump I have to put it in the blade or in the controller?